# Screen went black

Tags: console, tty

I'm new to Ubuntu..

I'm not sure what just happened, but the screen just went black with the text: 
**Ubuntu 11.10 "my computer name" tty4**

and I was asked to log on.

It happened when I closed Chrome (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>). This is the second time it has happened, and I cant make it go away :) Even if I log on. Only thing that works is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, which makes my PC restart.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Looks like you accidentally switched to the text console, that does no harm at all as long as you know how to return to your desktop. Did you accidentally hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>? In that case you can return to your desktop hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> until Ubuntu 16, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> starting at Ubuntu 18.

There are usually 6 text consoles (F1 - F6) but most users aren't even aware of them. They're extremely useful for troubleshooting, but otherwise barely used these years. I think the main use is in servers with usually no GUI (graphical user interface) available.

Comment: So helpful! Just want to note that on Linux Mint 14 I had to press Ctrl + Alt + F8 actually.

Comment: I had the same problem...I want to clarify that I had to use Ctrl + Fn + Super (? - key with Windows logo) + F7 on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: `Super`+`F4` and `Super`+`F7` do it for me.  Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.  It's rather unfortunate because my `Super` is next to `Alt`, which makes it easy to fat-finger `Alt`+`F4`, intending to close the foreground window.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu 20.04 this won't work. I followed @Tripatpal Singh's answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1058896/866008

Answer (score 18):

The [shortcut including the <kbd>F7</kbd> key](https://askubuntu.com/a/123494/) didn’t work for me in Ubuntu 18.04. Instead, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> worked to get back.

Comment: Works on Windows 10 as well, thank you!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20 as well.