# Alt + F4 switches to TTY4

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys, tty

Since yesterday <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> is working unexpectedly on my computer. When I press those keys TTY4 is opened. Also, the application which is running on the GUI receives the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> message. This is solved by rebooting the system, but after a while it starts doing this again.

As far as I have googled there are other people finding this problem but with no solutions ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59949/centos-avoid-that-alt-f4-switches-to-console), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801313/problems-with-tty-and-altf4)).

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.10, Kernel version 4.8.0-39-generic and GNOME Shell version 3.20.4.

Comment: Did you try the answer from the [second post you linked](http://askubuntu.com/questions/801313/problems-with-tty-and-altf4)?

Comment: You might want to check out this question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/123493/screen-went-black

Comment: @M.Becerra I don't have the package console-cyrillic installed on my system.

Comment: @DimitriMarkovich I did not hit Ctrl+Alt+F4, I am absolutely sure it's Alt+F4 which is doing what Ctrl+Alt+F4 should do.

Comment: Is your CTRL key physically stuck?  Jiggle the key and turn your keyboard upside down to clear potential crumbs.

Comment: Absolutely sure it's not. It is a software problem. When I reboot the pc it goes back to normal.

Comment: On Xenial, same problem (using Gnome)

Comment: same problem, also on Ubuntu Gnome

- Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64 bits
- GNOME Shell 3.18.5
- Linux 4.4.0-64-generic

Comment: This had stopped in the last two weeks but now it is happening again.

Comment: You are using a laptop or a desktop?
if it's a laptop, add the FN key

Comment: It is a laptop. What do you mean by "add the fn key"?

Comment: I faced the same problem right after upgrading some packages like: grub, linux-header, linux-image v4.4.0-21, etc. All combinations (Alt + F[1-6]) go to respective TTY; Alt+F7 go back to graphical session (but logged out). Solutions?

Comment: dont forget to use the function key

Comment: it seems related to a kernel upgrade, and it happens on other Linux distros: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59949/centos-avoid-that-alt-f4-switches-to-console

Comment: I only wanted to find out where I suddenly was, somehow dropped into that since I hit a bit of the *Alt* button as well while pressing *Alt+F4*, and this question helped me finding out that this is the tty, so that I could search further how to get back to my screen without entering the login, see [How can I leave tty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393160/how-can-i-leave-tty).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I had this recently on Ubuntu GNOME and on Unity. The answer is this:

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

Run that in a terminal and then the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> keyboard combination returns to normal.

From [`kbd_mode` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/kbd_mode.1.html) (from [kbd project](http://www.kbd-project.org/) and [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kbd)):

> **kbd_mode** - report or set the keyboard mode
>
> Without  argument,  kbd_mode  prints  the current keyboard mode (RAW, MEDIUMRAW or XLATE).
> With argument, it sets the keyboard mode as indicated:
>
> `-s`: scancode mode (RAW),

Comment: Running `sudo kbd_mode` before the above command showed me that my keyboard was in “Unicode (UTF-8) mode”. The above command will set your keyboard mode to “raw (scancode) mode”, as [`man kbd_mode`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kbd_mode) can verify.

Comment: Just for future reference for others, this works in 18.04 as well (it uses GNOME by default).

Comment: And sudo kbd_mode -u to switch back to unicode mode

Comment: It is really annoying to have to do this for every boot, apparently a permanent solution is to edit /etc/console-setup/remap.inc as described by https://askubuntu.com/a/1059609/104605 .

Answer (score 1):

1. As root, edit `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc`.
2. Add this line at the bottom:

   ```
   alt     keycode  62 = VoidSymbol
   ```
3. Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup -phigh`
4. Reboot (`reboot`).

The problem should be fixed now. At least it worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

Things to do

```
1. Alt + f1
```

- what will above do? Will it open TTY1?

```
2. open terminal and just press "j" without quote
```

what is the output? will it work same as pressing enter key? or just prints "j"?

In the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801313/problems-with-tty-and-altf4) you posted @Pielco11  says `sudo update-grub` solves the problem.

Also try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: When this happens, Alt+F1 opens TTY1. I haven't tried pressing J on a terminal  specifically but I know that other commands using Ctrl work fine.

Comment: can you confirm what will happen if you just press "j" in terminal? Open terminal with ctrl + Atl +T

Comment: I tried what you asked and it just prints "j".

Answer (score -4):

Some ideas to trace down and maybe fix the issue:

- Booting with a Live-CD in order to check if the problem is physical
- Use another keyboard
- Switch the keyboard layout or try to remap the Ctrl
- Does it only happen on the desktop environment or does it also switch to TTY4 if you are at some other TTY? If it happens also on the TTYs, it might be related to some kernel parameter.

Did you try the tip on the last comment of your second reference (update-grub)?

Comment: It is definitely not physical.  Yes, I have updated grub.

Comment: Have you tried booting from a live CD? I happen to have a similar problem right now and I am comparing settings between a good and a bad machine.
If a live CD session works properly, you could try to compare the outputs of, for example:  `env`, `locale`, `localectl` or `locale charmap`.

Comment: The thing is my computer works normally most of times. This just happens from time to time, so it is hard to compare.

Comment: It sounds like a tricky problem. Maybe you could make a script that outputs all the related information and save it into a file (including all commands above). Then run it again when the problem reappears and make a `diff` or something with both files.