# ubuntu 18.04 upgrade : only option is kodi. please provide steps to install desktop.

Tags: unity, upgrade, 18.04

upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from 16.04 LTS today. But on login screen only option for Kodi is available on the gear icon.

a). Appreciate Any suggestions/steps available to install desktop on it. 
b). Is all data from old unity desktop lost (chrome bookmarks/files) ? i feel i made a mistake to upgrade ubuntu.

[login screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANBdj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

First I would try to run all of your upgrades:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Then make sure you have gdm3 installed:

```
sudo apt install gdm3
```

Then reboot and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua  :

thanks!

followed steps to get the updates:
a). [How do I access console from GDM ? (wayland)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028328/how-do-i-access-console-from-gdm-wayland)
~ but getting file system is read-only mode

next tried 
b). [What to do after Failed to start Load Kernel Modules](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779251/what-to-do-after-failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules)
executed commands ~
apt-get update;
dpkg --configure -a;
apt-get dist-upgrade;
apt-get -f install;

but i feel the ethernet port is not working hence not getting the updates. 
Will try the above steps on a loaner PC with working ethernet port & report back.

+++++++++

moved HDD to another loaner laptop & tried to run the updates command but still unable to get the updates. I am unable to resolve error "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules" .
Somehow got the file system to be read/write mode but still stuck with Kodi.

Will try out something else otherwise I will go back to 16.04 on a new hdd & try to recover data from drive.

+++++++++++

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326216
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884940/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules-on-ubuntu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943

I am giving up on this & going back to 16.04. Above suggestions did not work for me.