# Kubuntu 18.04 switching to terminal

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, 18.04

After fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04 I'm experiencing a really annoying issue.

After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (to quickly execute something) I'm, thrown into the terminal - or console - or tty2 - simply completely out of GUI.

Then I need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get back to GUI and then the quick launch is displayed.

Similar goes for <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>.

Is there any hack how to disable this behaviour?

Comment: That's not normal. It shouldn't happen.

Comment: @dsstorefile1, I have `console-setup-linux/bionic,now 1.178ubuntu2 all [installed]` and didn't see anything like what OP describes.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 oh my god, restart actually helped! Who could think of that ;)

Comment: I had this installed as part of the initial installtion which I did on 2018-04-26. I haven't had any updates to this particular package since then.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here https://askubuntu.com/a/929115/248158 and here https://askubuntu.com/a/1073515/39176. For completeness

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

(persistent across reboots).