# TTY hotkeys changed

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, tty

For some reason, my tty hotkeys have changed. The following things used to happen:

- Alt+F4 would close windows
- If I'm inside PyCharm, Alt-Left and Alt-Right allow me to move between functions forward and backward
- Alt+F3 (perhaps plus ctrl, dont remember) and Alt+F7/Alt+F8 were TTY hotkeys (I think  F8 used to go back to the default)

Now, all the aforementioned hotkeys link to TTYs, and Alt+F2 goes back to the default. I can't recall having changed any hotkey, but I'm on LTS 18.04 and installed several updates recently and only yesterday had my first reboot. Perhaps that's related?

What happened, and how can I get my previous hotkey scheme back?

Comment: I had the same problem after the last update, and the accepted answer here worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/886593/alt-f4-switches-to-tty4?noredirect=1&lq=1