# Alt + Tab + arrow keys behavior changed to shift to TTY instead of move between open windows

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is the combination to switch between running programs. Also, if I hold <kbd>alt</kbd> after pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> once I can then use the arrow keys to go right or left and select the program I need.

But all of a sudden, without making any changes, when I click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> I get the prompt to log in to a new shell on tty3, tty4, tty5 etc.

Why did this happen and how can I change it to the old behavior?

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/886593/alt-f4-switches-to-tty4 and https://askubuntu.com/a/929115/248158 in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
sudo kbd_mode -s
```

My keyboard was in “Unicode (UTF-8) mode”. The above command will set your keyboard mode to “raw (scancode) mode”

Thanks to DK Bose